# how i can fix this error BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::medicine does not exist. in file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am trying to make a relation (many to many) betwen tow tables in D.B

i want to create a row in the table of conaction betwen the tables

the controller is

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $validator =validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'scientific_name'=>'required'|'min:4'|'max:25',
                'trade_name'=>'required'|'min:4'|'max:20',
                'category'=>'required'|'min:4'|'max:20',
                'company'=>'required'|'min:4'|'max:20',
                'quantity'=>'required'|'numeric',
                'Ex_D'=>'required',
                'praic'=>'required'|'numeric',
                'user_id'=>'required',
            ],
            [
                
            ]

            );
            if ($validator==false){
                return response()->json([
                    'massage'=>'validator error',
                    'error'=> $validator->errors()->all()
                ],400);
            }
            $prodact= Medicine::create([
                'scientific_name'=>$request->scientific_name,
                'trade_name'=>$request->trade_name,
                'category'=>$request->category,
                'company'=>$request->company,
                'quantity'=>$request->quantity,
                'Ex_D'=>$request->Ex_D,
                'praic'=>$request->praic,
            ]);
            $id=$prodact->id;
            $warehouse=Warehouse::with('medicine')->get();
            $warehouse->medicine()->attach([$id]);
```

the model is

```
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'

    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'timestamps',
        'user_id',
        'id',
    ];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function medicine(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Medicine::class);
    }
}
```

the D.Bs are conacted with eche other but i can not create a row in the table of conaction

am new in thes fremwark

Comment: `$warehouse=Warehouse::with('medicine')->get();` `->get()` returns a Collection of `Warehouse` instances. `->medicine()` will only work **on a single `Medicine` instance. So you either need to use `->first()`, or loop over your records.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call medicine() method on a collection of records:

```
$warehouse=Warehouse::with('medicine')->get();
$warehouse->medicine()->attach([$id]);
```

the ->get(); returns an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection class, which does not in fact have the medicine() method.

You need to either loop through all the records one by one:

```
$warehouses = Warehouse::with('medicine')->get();
foreach ($warehouses as $warehouse){
     $warehouse->medicine()->attach([$id]);
}
```

Or just take one warehouse record:

```
$warehouse = Warehouse::with('medicine')->first();
$warehouse->medicine()->attach([$id]);
```